# visualizing progress on git repositories

Tags: git, project-management, visualization

Is there a tool to visualize how much progress have been made on the git project over time? Something that can graph productivity over days/weeks/months in a chart is what I'm thinking of.

If not, is it possible to extract git history data into some kind of format (xml etc) to process (and later visualize) manually?

Comment: Probably not what you're looking for, but check out [gource](http://code.google.com/p/gource/).

Comment: @MarkRushakoff, I saw videos of this on youtube, and finally found Gource. Thanks buddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at gitstats, which uses GNU Plot to visualize a repo's history of activity:

http://gitstats.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 4):

I know that github and other hosts show this already. But it wouldn't be hard to automate something like that:

```
git log --no-merges --author="Jane" --format="%ai" --all
```

This will show the dates of all the commits of Jane. You can stream that to a file with `> export.csv` at the end. You then open this with excel where you can manipulate the data. Or you can export each author and their commits:

```
git log --no-merges --all --format=" %an %ai"
```

further, you could dig out more info about each commit (say the number of lines changed each time, or paths affected, etc..)

```
for sha1 in $(git log --no-merges --format="%H" master@{"1 month ago"}..master); do
    git log -1 --format=" --- %an %ai ---" $sha1 >> tempfile
    git log --stat -1 $sha1 >> tempfile
    # some other processing
done
```

This time I've limited the output to where master was last month.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git shortlog --since="1 month ago"`.  Or you can use the `--format` option to `git log` to output information in a format suitable for how you want to plot things.